# Using google.charts.load once time for multiple chart types

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to make a plugin with google chart, like this:

```js
(function (global) {
    'use strict';

    if (!global.google || !global.google.charts) {
        let s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = `//www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js`;

        document.head.appendChild(s);
    }

    let google = {};

    google.ready = function (_) {
        let t = setInterval(function () {
            if (global.google && global.google.charts) {
                clearInterval(t);

                _.call(global.google);
            }
        }, 1);    
    };

    let chart = (function () {
        let _selector = Symbol('GoogleChart');

        class GoogleChart {
            constructor(selector) {
                this[_selector] = selector;
            }
            CoreChart(options = {}) {
                let _this = this, selector = document.getElementById(_this[_selector]);

                let init = function () {
                    let google = this;

                    let drawChart = function () {

                        let O = {
                            width: options.width || 500,
                            height: options.height || 500,
                            legend: options.legend || {},
                            pointSize: options.pointSize || 1,
                            vAxis: options.vAxis || {},
                            hAxis: options.hAxis || {},
                            series: options.series || {},
                            colors: options.colors || [],
                            lineWidth: options.lineWidth || 2
                        };

                        let data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                        if (!options.data || !options.data.columns || !options.data.rows) throw `Missing 'data'. No data to display in the chart.`;
                        
                        for (let column in options.data.columns) data.addColumn(column, options.data.columns[column]);

                        if (options.tooltip && options.tooltip.type) {
                            let tooltip = {
                                type: options.tooltip.type,
                                role: 'tooltip'
                            };

                            if (options.tooltip.isHtml) {
                                tooltip.p = {
                                    html: true
                                };
                                
                                O.tooltip = {
                                    isHtml: true
                                };
                            }

                            data.addColumn(tooltip);
                        }

                        data.addRows(options.data.rows);
                        
                        //
                        let chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(selector);

                        //
                        chart.draw(data, O);
                    };

                    google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                };

                //
                google.ready(init);
            }
        }
        return GoogleChart;
    }());
        
    global.GoogleChart = chart;
}(window));





// USAGE:





let chart = new GoogleChart('line');
chart.CoreChart({
    width: 500,
    height: 200,
    data: {
        columns: {
            'string': 'Date',
            'number': 'Date'
        },
        rows: [
            ['1', 2],
            ['', 7],
            ['3', 3],
            ['', 9],
            ['5', 3],
            ['', 1],
            ['7', 4],
            ['', 6],
            ['9', 3],
            ['', 5],
            ['11', 8],
            ['', 2],
            ['13', 1],
            ['', 0],
            ['15', 8]
        ]
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'top'
    },
    series: {
        0: {
            color: '#f00',
            lineDashStyle: [2, 2, 20, 2, 20, 2]
        }
    },
    pointSize: 3
});
```

```html
<div id="line"></div>
```

It works fine with only 1 chart type (`CoreChart`). Now, I want to support more chart types ([Geo chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart), [Map chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map)).

```
let chart1 = new GoogleChart(selector1);
chart1.GeoChart(options);

let chart2 = new GoogleChart(selector2);
chart2.MapChart(options);
```

I notice [the Limitations:](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#limitations)

> You can only call **google.charts.load** *once*. But you can list all the packages that you'll need in one call, so there's no need to make separate calls.

So, my plugin doesn't know exactly the chart type until it's called (`.GeoChart` or `.MapChart`). If there are multiple charts on a page, how to draw it?

If I do this:

```
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'geochart', 'map'] });
```

and there is no `GeoChart` or `MapChart` called, that would be wasting (spending time to load the unused charts).

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: You can call google.charts.load more than one time now. The limitation is only for older versions.